# execute code in files without importing them in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():  
           print('writing multiple lines in a file through user input')  
           infile=open("xyz.txt", "w")  
           for line in iter(input, ''):  
                infile.write(line + '\n');  
           infile.close()  
           infile=open("xyz.txt", "r")  

           for line in infile:  
                print(line)  
           infile.close()'  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the main program and i have attached the output file as well which i want the output to be executed.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9o1C.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a python file by invoking a python subprocess:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python3', 'xyz.txt'])
```

This will run python3 and execute the script in the "xyz.txt" file. This code has only been tested on Linux/Mac, so if you are on windows you may have to put the full path to python3 where it is installed - haven't tested, sorry.

Comment: thank you for your help. can you refer me the books which i can learn python from intermediate to full advance including networking

Comment: I'd highly suggest "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way: A Very Simple Introduction to the Terrifyingly Beautiful World of Computers and Code By Zed A. Shaw". It is available on Oreilly and other websites. This book is great for beginners, and teaches you almost everything you need to start writing python scripts / games / websites. The book however DOESNT cover networking. Networking is more involved, so once you read and understand this book, google tutorials on python networking.

Answer (score -2):

Use the inbuilt os library

```
import os

os.system("python other_file.py")
```

This way you can use any commands from the os environment, so the possibilities are not limited to python.

But if you would like to read the output of the given script you subprocess instead

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("python 2.py", shell=True)
print(output)
```

Comment: Always use `subprocess`, not `os.system`, and never use it with `shell=True`. From a stability and security perspective, getting the shell involved is a terrible idea.